# Regular rexpression in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is an error I am getting when I am run the code:

```
import re

pat = ['ashu', 'gupta']

text = "my name is ashutosh gupta"

for pattern in pat:
    print('i am seraching for:  '+pattern)

if re.search(pat, text):
    print("Match")
else:
    print("NOT mactch")
```

Error is below:

```
i am seraching for:  ashu
i am seraching for:  gupta
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Regular_expression.py", line 11, in <module>
    if re.search(pat,text):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 237, in _compile
    p, loc = _cache[cachekey]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: you are passing `pat` (which happens to be a list) in `re.search` take a look at [https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search], it expects regex string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

pat = ['ashu', 'gupta']

text = "my name is ashutosh gupta"

for pattern in pat:
    print('i am seraching for:  '+pattern)

    if re.search(pattern, text):
        print("Match")
    else:
        print("NOT mactch")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the question is already answered by @jishad av above.
But i dont think that you would require using re in this case.

```
pat = ['ashu', 'gupta']
text = "my name is ashutosh gupta"
for pattern in pat:
    print('i am seraching for:  '+pattern)
    if pattern in text:
        print("Match)
    else:
        print("Not Match")
```